# Какое предложение составлено правильно?

Tags: синтаксис, деепричастный-оборот

Чувство патриотизма охватывает нас, слушая гимн родной страны.

Учитель вдруг понял, что растрачивает свою жизнь впустую, проверяя одни и те же задания и не внося ничего нового в уроки.

Взглянув на дождь за окном, мне стало грустно.

Готовясь к экзаменам, у вас должны быть законспектированы все лекции.

Comment: @zaxar z, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Второе (если пробел добавить после запятой). В остальных предложениях деепричастия связаны не с теми словами.

**P.S.** Деепричастный оборот обычно направлен на подлежащее. Если подлежащего нет (безличное предложение), то оборот повисает в воздухе (третье предложение). Классический пример. **Подъезжая к станции, у меня слетела шляпа.** Из этого буквально следует, что "шляпа подъезжала к станции". Соответственно, здесь в первом предложении "чувство слушает гимн", в последнем - "лекции (сами) готовятся к экзаменам".